# How to convert SVM values into corresponding class type?

Tags: r, classification, svm, confusion-matrix

I am doing SVM on R, and when I do:

```
fit2 = svm(satisfied~PC1 + PC2 + PC3 + PC4, data=data.frame(train.incl.score.x.y.st), kernel="radial", cost=5, gamma=500)

pred2=predict(fit2, data.frame(val.incl.score[,1:4]),  probabiltiy=FALSE)

table(pred2, data.frame(val.incl.score.x.y.st)$satisfied)

>> pred2.                  0 1
  -8.37175892132423        1 0
  -7.98589263979825        1 0
  -6.74777840420131        1 0
  -6.70935986153772        1 0
  -6.46316720580385        1 0
  -6.04268844390794        1 0

 <list goes on...>
```

What I want is I want the column pred2 in the output above to display the predicted class type instead of the numerical value that the SVM model assigns to each observation. How can I get the predicted class type for each validation observation, and make confusion matrix accordingly?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before, and it was because the response variable was numeric, rather than factor.  As a result, the SVM was doing regression, rather than classification.

Have you checked to see if 'satisfied' is a factor variable? I think that should resolve it.